# Different output from PHP script at the browser and at android app

Tags: php, android

I am working on an android app.

I need to retrieve data from a remote MySQL database.

I am using the following PHP script to send a JSON array to the app:

```
<?php 

require_once 'dbconnect.php';
    $con->set_charset("utf8");

    //Checking if any error occured while connecting
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }

    //creating a query
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT spo.id_spot,spo.sport_spot,spo.type_spot,spo.date_upload_spot,spo.description_spot,spo.city_spot,spo.country_spot,spo.latitud_spot,
    spo.longitud_spot,spo.verified_spot,spo.verified_spot_by,spo.short_name,mediaspottype,mediaspotfiles,st.name_spot_type,st.logo_spot_type,st.diametro_spot_type FROM tb_spots spo 

LEFT join users u ON spo.uploaded_by = u.id

LEFT Join tb_sports sp1 ON sp1.id_sport = spo.sport_spot
LEFT JOIN tb_spot_types st ON st.id_spot_type = spo.type_spot
LEFT JOIN tb_spot_media pme On pme.media_spot = spo.id_spot 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT media_spot, GROUP_CONCAT(media_type) AS mediaspottype ,GROUP_CONCAT(media_file) AS mediaspotfiles 
   FROM tb_spot_media 
   GROUP BY media_spot
) AS pm ON pm.media_spot = spo.id_spot
GROUP BY spo.id_spot

");

    //executing the query 
    $stmt->execute();

    //binding results to the query 
    $stmt->bind_result($id_spot,$sport_spot,$type_spot,$date_upload_spot,$description_spot,$city_spot,$country_spot,$latitud_spot,
    $longitud_spot,$verified_spot,$verified_spot_by,$short_name,$mediaspottype,$mediaspotfiles,$name_spot_type,$logo_spot_type,$diametro_spot_type);

    $products = array(); 

    //traversing through all the result 
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $temp = array();
        $temp['id_spot'] = $id_spot; 
        $temp['sport_spot'] = $sport_spot;
        $temp['type_spot'] = $type_spot; 

        $temp['date_upload_spot'] = $date_upload_spot; 
        $temp['description_spot'] = $description_spot;
        $temp['city_spot'] = $city_spot;
        $temp['country_spot'] = $country_spot;
        $temp['latitud_spot'] = $latitud_spot;
        $temp['longitud_spot'] = $longitud_spot;
        $temp['verified_spot'] = $verified_spot;
        $temp['verified_spot_by'] = $verified_spot_by;
        $temp['short_name'] = $short_name;
        $temp['mediaspottype'] = $mediaspottype;
        $temp['mediaspotfiles'] = $mediaspotfiles;
        $temp['name_spot_type'] = $name_spot_type;
            $temp['logo_spot_type'] = $logo_spot_type;
            $temp['diametro_spot_type'] = $diametro_spot_type;
        array_push($products, $temp);
    }

    //displaying the result in json format 
    echo json_encode($products);
```

The script is working as it should, at least when executed from the browser. It shows 10 items.

The issue is when called by the app, it sends 15 items.

I guess the issue must be at the GROUP BY spo.id_spot line.

The query shows 15 items if not grouped by spo.id_spot.

But I don´t understand the issue if the PHP works when executed directly on the browser.

This is the android part:

```
private void loadspots() {


StringRequest stringRequestspots = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_SPOTS,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    //converting the string to json array object
                    spotsArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    editor.putString("spotsArray", spotsArray.toString() );
                    editor.apply();





                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

//adding our stringrequest to queue

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequestspots);
```

}

Comment: are you passing your id with the request url ?

Comment: @VivekMishra,no need for it. All items should be shown. There is no  WHERE part at the query.

Comment: @VivekMishra, I guess it could be a Volley cache issue..

Comment: you said that in your question is that your group by clause is not working.So you should send the id somehow with your request

Comment: Or are you using static id ?

Comment: @VivekMishra, it has nothing to do with the app user´s id.

Comment: @VivekMishra, confirmed. Disabling Volley cache solves the issue.

Comment: Just for sake of sanity, here is your mysqli code reduced by half doing the same job https://3v4l.org/TPE7r

Comment: @YourCommonSense, nice proposal. Thank you

Comment: If the volley cache thing solved your issue, please post that as an answer to your question & accept it after the... two days, I think.

Comment: @Reed, done. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue disabling the Volley cache.